# Create a random within a range from an ArrayList within an Arraylist

Tags: java, random, arraylist

I am at the end of my program here and Im trying to create a random number thats in an arraylist. I have the syntax below that Im using. I don't know how to write this, but I hope the code shows what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class TriviaQuestionTester  {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     File gameFile = new File("trivia.txt");
     String nextLine, category;
     int cat1 = 0;
     int cat2 = 0;
     int cat3 = 0;
     int cat4 = 0;
     int cat5 = 0;
     int cat6 = 0;
     int random1, random2, random3, random4, random5, random6;
     int totalScore = 0;
     int awardedPoints = 200;
     String answer;
     Random random = new Random();
     Scanner inFile = new Scanner(gameFile);
     Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     ArrayList <String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();   

     //append @ sign to first index of arraylist when we copy the text file into it. first line will 
     //be the first category.
    category = "@"+ inFile.nextLine();
    //add category to arraylist
    myList.add(category);
    //while textfile has another line of input, write that line into the arraylist.
    while (inFile.hasNextLine()){
        nextLine = inFile.nextLine();
        //check if the next line is blank. if it is, advance to the next line (as it must be a category) and append @ sign
        //before copying it into the arraylist. if it is not, write the line into the arraylist.
        if(nextLine.equals("")){
            category = "@"+ inFile.nextLine();
            myList.add(category);
        } else {
            myList.add(nextLine);
        }
    }
    //close the text file from reading
    inFile.close();


    System.out.println("Steve's Crazy Trivia Game!!!!" );
    System.out.println("");


    //find categories by searching the contents of every arraylist index and looking for the @ sign.
    //when you find that, assign that into the respective variable.
    int q = 1;
    for(int j = 0; j < myList.size(); j++){
        if(myList.get(j).contains("@")){
            //System.out.println("Category found at " + j);
            if(q == 1){
                cat1 = j;
            }
            if(q == 2){
                cat2 = j;
            }
            if(q == 3){
                cat3 = j;
            }
            if(q == 4){
                cat4 = j;
            }
            if(q == 5){
                cat5 = j;
            }
            if(q == 6){
                cat6 = j;
            }
            q++;
        }
    }


    //first question
    //get category from variable, print it to user without the @ sign
    System.out.println("Category: " + myList.get(cat1).substring(1));
    //generate a random number in a range 1 more than the index where the category is and 2 less than
    //where the next category is to get a question (always will be odd numbers)
    //Credit: Derek Teay
    random1 = random.nextInt(((cat2 - 2) - (cat1 + 1))) + (cat1 + 1);
    //debug code - shows the number generated
    //System.out.println("Random number: " + random1);
    //take the modulus of the random number. if there is a remainder, the number is odd, continue.
    //if there is not a remainder, number is even, generate a new number until the randomly generated
    //number is odd.
    while (random1 % 2 == 0){
        random1 = random.nextInt(((cat2 - 2) - (cat1 + 1))) + (cat1 + 1);
        //debug code - shows the new random number if the first number isn't odd
        //System.out.println("New random number: " + random1);
    }
    //display the question to the user
    System.out.println("Question: " + myList.get(random1));
    //accept user input
    System.out.print("Please type your answer: ");
    //store the user answer in a variable but lowercase
    answer = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    System.out.println();
    //display the officially correct answer from the arraylist
    //System.out.println("Answer: " + myList.get(random1 +1));
    //if the user answer matches the official answer, tell them they're correct and award points - else
    //tell them they are incorrect
    // Display the officially correct answer from the arraylist
    String correctAnswer =  myList.get(random1 +1); 
    System.out.println("Answer: " + correctAnswer); // Instead use a variable

    // if the user answer matches the official answer, tell them they're
    // correct and award points
    // else tell them they suck LOL
    if(correctAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase(answer.trim())) { 
        System.out.println("Correct!");
        totalScore = totalScore + awardedPoints;
        System.out.println("You won " + awardedPoints);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("You are incorrect");
    }

    //display total accumulated points
    System.out.println("Your total points are: " + totalScore);
    //wait for user to hit any key before displaying the next question
    System.out.print("Hit Enter");
    System.out.println("");
    scanner.nextLine(); 



            //second question
            //get category from variable, print it to user without the @ sign
            System.out.println("Category: " + myList.get(cat2).substring(1));
            //generate a random number in a range 1 more than the index where the category is and 2 less than
            //where the next category is to get a question (always will be odd numbers)
            //Credit: Derek Teay
            random2 = random.nextInt(((cat3 - 2) - (cat2 + 1))) + (cat2 + 1);

            //take the modulus of the random number. if there is a remainder, the number is odd, continue.
            //if there is not a remainder, number is even, generate a new number until the randomly generated
            //number is odd.
            while (random2 % 2 == 0){
                random2 = random.nextInt(((cat3 - 2) - (cat2 + 1))) + (cat2 + 1);
            }
            //display the question to the user
            System.out.println("Question: " + myList.get(random2 + 1));
            //accept user input
            System.out.print("Please type your answer: ");
            //store the user answer in a variable but lowercase
            answer = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            System.out.println();

            //if the user answer matches the official answer, tell them they're correct and award points - else
            //tell them they are incorrect
            // Display the officially correct answer from the arraylist
            String correctAnswer1 =  myList.get(random2 +1); 
            System.out.println("Answer: " + correctAnswer1); // Instead use a variable

            // if the user answer matches the official answer, tell them they're
            // correct and award points
            // else tell them they suck LOL
            if(correctAnswer1.equalsIgnoreCase(answer.trim())) { 
                System.out.println("Correct!");
                totalScore = totalScore + awardedPoints;
                System.out.println("You won " + awardedPoints);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("You are wrong again");
            }

            //display total accumulated points
            System.out.println("Your total points are: " + totalScore);
            //wait for user to hit any key before displaying the next question
            System.out.print("Hit Enter");
            System.out.println("");
            scanner.nextLine(); 

            //third question
            //get category from variable, print it to user without the @ sign
            System.out.println("Category: " + myList.get(cat3).substring(1));
            //generate a random number in a range 1 more than the index where the category is and 2 less than
            //where the next category is to get a question (always will be odd numbers)
            //Credit: Derek Teay
            random3 = random.nextInt(((cat4 - 2) - (cat3 + 1))) + (cat3 + 1);

            //take the modulus of the random number. if there is a remainder, the number is odd, continue.
            //if there is not a remainder, number is even, generate a new number until the randomly generated
            //number is odd.
            while (random3 % 2 == 0){
                random3 = random.nextInt(((cat4 - 2) - (cat3 + 1))) + (cat3 + 1);
            }
            //display the question to the user
            System.out.println("Question: " + myList.get(random3 + 1));
            //accept user input
            System.out.print("Please type your answer: ");
            //store the user answer in a variable but lowercase
            answer = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            System.out.println();

            //if the user answer matches the official answer, tell them they're correct and award points - else
            //tell them they are incorrect
            // Display the officially correct answer from the arraylist
            String correctAnswer2 =  myList.get(random3 +1); 
            System.out.println("Answer: " + correctAnswer1); // Instead use a variable

            // if the user answer matches the official answer, tell them they're
            // correct and award points
            // else tell them they suck LOL
            if(correctAnswer2.equalsIgnoreCase(answer.trim())) { 
                System.out.println("Correct!");
                totalScore = totalScore + awardedPoints;
                System.out.println("You won " + awardedPoints);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Wow, you really stink");
            }

            //display total accumulated points
            System.out.println("Your total points are: " + totalScore);
            //wait for user to hit any key before displaying the next question
            System.out.print("Hit Enter");
            System.out.println("");
            scanner.nextLine(); 

            //fourth question
            //get category from variable, print it to user without the @ sign
            System.out.println("Category: " + myList.get(cat4).substring(1));
            //generate a random number in a range 1 more than the index where the category is and 2 less than
            //where the next category is to get a question (always will be odd numbers)
            //Credit: Derek Teay
            random4 = random.nextInt(((cat5 - 2) - (cat4 + 1))) + (cat4 + 1);

            //take the modulus of the random number. if there is a remainder, the number is odd, continue.
            //if there is not a remainder, number is even, generate a new number until the randomly generated
            //number is odd.
            while (random4 % 2 == 0){
                random4 = random.nextInt(((cat5 - 2) - (cat4 + 1))) + (cat4 + 1);
            }
            //display the question to the user
            System.out.println("Question: " + myList.get(random4 + 1));
            //accept user input
            System.out.print("Please type your answer: ");
            //store the user answer in a variable but lowercase
            answer = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            System.out.println();

            //if the user answer matches the official answer, tell them they're correct and award points - else
            //tell them they are incorrect
            // Display the officially correct answer from the arraylist
            String correctAnswer3 =  myList.get(random4 +1); 
            System.out.println("Answer: " + correctAnswer3); // Instead use a variable

            // if the user answer matches the official answer, tell them they're
            // correct and award points
            // else tell them they suck LOL
            if(correctAnswer3.equalsIgnoreCase(answer.trim())) { 
                System.out.println("Correct!");
                totalScore = totalScore + awardedPoints;
                System.out.println("You won " + awardedPoints);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("You are incorrect");
            }

            //display total accumulated points
            System.out.println("Your total points are: " + totalScore);
            //wait for user to hit any key before displaying the next question
            System.out.print("Hit Enter");
            System.out.println("");
            scanner.nextLine(); 

            //fifth question
            //get category from variable, print it to user without the @ sign
            //generate a random number in a range 1 more than the index where the category is and 2 less than
            //where the next category is to get a question (always will be odd numbers)
            //Credit: Derek Teay
            random5 = random.nextInt(((cat6 - 2) - ( cat5 + 1))) + (cat5 + 1);

            //take the modulus of the random number. if there is a remainder, the number is odd, continue.
            //if there is not a remainder, number is even, generate a new number until the randomly generated
            //number is odd.
            while (random5 % 2 == 0){
                random5 = random.nextInt(((cat6 - 2) - (cat5 + 1))) + (cat5 + 1);
            }
            //display the question to the user
            System.out.println("Question: " + myList.get(random5 + 1));
            //accept user input
            System.out.print("Please type your answer: ");
            //store the user answer in a variable but lowercase
            answer = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            System.out.println();

            //if the user answer matches the official answer, tell them they're correct and award points - else
            //tell them they are incorrect
            // Display the officially correct answer from the arraylist
            String correctAnswer4 =  myList.get(random5 +1); 
            System.out.println("Answer: " + correctAnswer4); // Instead use a variable

            // if the user answer matches the official answer, tell them they're
            // correct and award points
            // else tell them they suck LOL
            if(correctAnswer4.equalsIgnoreCase(answer.trim())) { 
                System.out.println("Correct!");
                totalScore = totalScore + awardedPoints;
                System.out.println("You won " + awardedPoints);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("You are incorrect");
            }

            //display total accumulated points
            System.out.println("Your total points are: " + totalScore);
            //wait for user to hit any key before displaying the next question
            System.out.print("Hit Enter");
            System.out.println("");
            scanner.nextLine(); 

            //sixth question
            //get category from variable, print it to user without the @ sign
            System.out.println("Category: " + myList.get(cat6).substring(1));
            //generate a random number in a range 1 more than the index where the category is and 2 less than
            //where the next category is to get a question (always will be odd numbers)
            //Credit: Derek Teay
            random6 = random.nextInt((cat6.maximum - cat6.minimum) + (cat6.minimum));

            //take the modulus of the random number. if there is a remainder, the number is odd, continue.
            //if there is not a remainder, number is even, generate a new number until the randomly generated
            //number is odd.
            while (random6 % 2 == 0){
                random6 = random.nextInt(((cat3 - 2) - (cat2 + 1))) + (cat2 + 1);
            }
            //display the question to the user
            System.out.println("Question: " + myList.get(random6 + 1));
            //accept user input
            System.out.print("Please type your answer: ");
            //store the user answer in a variable but lowercase
            answer = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            System.out.println();

            //if the user answer matches the official answer, tell them they're correct and award points - else
            //tell them they are incorrect
            // Display the officially correct answer from the arraylist
            String correctAnswer5 =  myList.get(random6 +1); 
            System.out.println("Answer: " + correctAnswer5); // Instead use a variable

            // if the user answer matches the official answer, tell them they're
            // correct and award points
            // else tell them they suck LOL
            if(correctAnswer1.equalsIgnoreCase(answer.trim())) { 
                System.out.println("Correct!");
                totalScore = totalScore + awardedPoints;
                System.out.println("You won " + awardedPoints);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Did you even go to school?");
            }

            //display total accumulated points
            System.out.println("Your total points are: " + totalScore);
            //wait for user to hit any key before displaying the next question
            System.out.print("Hit Enter");
            System.out.println("");
            scanner.nextLine(); 
    }

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: What I was originally doing for the prior 5 categories was take 1 away from the start of the next category and the start of the category i was working on. But I am at my last category and Im not sure how to keep a random number between the indexes of that particular index in that array.

Comment: `((cat6.maximum - cat6.minimum) + (cat6.minimum))` This seems redundant.

Comment: `(cat6.maximum - cat6.minimum) + (cat6.minimum)` will be equal `cat6.maximum`

Comment: That very well may be, but I was hoping it would work. But eclipse doesnt like it

Comment: Do you mean something more like `random6 = random.nextInt(cat6.maximum - cat6.minimum) + cat6.minimum;` perhaps?

Comment: What does Eclipse complains about?

Comment: It says the primitive type int of cat6 doesnt have a field minimum

Comment: Yea... we need to see a lot more code then...

Comment: Ok, I have posted the entire code from this class so you can see my logic, although as flawed as it may be, does function. But once I hit the final question I cant use the same stuff because there is no category 7

Comment: That might be too much.  Maybe... I guess I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Note that nextInt returns a "value between 0 (inclusive) and n (exclusive)". This means that the result will always be < cat6.maximum. Make sure that's what you want.

Comment: What range in terms of literal numbers are you looking for with your calls to random?

Comment: It needs to be between line 135 and line 157 from the file that is read. Once all the lines are read in category 6 that belong there I need a way to make sure that Im dealing with the odd number lines because that way Ill know im dealing with a question on the trivia game

Comment: So, odd number lines are questions and even number lines are the answers?

Comment: That is correct, and I am trying to single out the odds so that I can display a question then compare it to the very next line.

Comment: Hmm... okay, I'm starting to make sense of what your program is doing now... and it's a bit of a mess.  You've got a big array of strings.  Some of the indexes are questions, some are answers, and some are category headers.  Quite a mess.  So, you code organize your code better and make the random issue your having simpler by implementing some object oriented techniques, if you're up for it.

Comment: Just trying to figure out how to take this mess of a text file and make it function for my class was a beast of a job for me. I would really like to continue to work with it and make it better, but after a week and half this is the best I got so far. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well first off your line:

```
random6 = random.nextInt((cat6.maximum - cat6.minimum) + (cat6.minimum));
```

should be:

```
random6 = random.nextInt(cat6.maximum - cat6.minimum) + cat6.minimum;
```

You're using an awful lot of parentheses so it gets hard to see, but the minimum value should go *outside* the call to `nextInt()` because `nextInt()` returns a value of the range [0, max - min) but you want one in the range [min, max).

Next, you can do this:

```
while ((random6 = random.nextInt(cat6.maximum - cat6.minimum) + cat6.minimum) % 2 == 0) {
    continue;
}
```

**EDIT**: Well, after looking at your full code a bit more...

Learn to use and love functions. Here, what you're doing (getting an index of a random question based on a category index) is complex and discrete enough to be its own function:

```
//generate a random number in a range 1 more than the index where the category is and 2 less than
//where the next category is to get a question (always will be odd numbers)
public static int getRandomQuestionIndex(int category) {
    int min = category - 2;
    int max = category + 2; // Because nextInt() is exclusive on upper bound
    int random6;
    while ((random6 = random.nextInt(max - min) + min) % 2 == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    return random6;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't really understand what your goal is, but I think there's a bug on this line:

```
random6 = random.nextInt((cat6.maximum - cat6.minimum) + (cat6.minimum));
```

Your parentheses aren't quite right. It should be:

```
random6 = random.nextInt((cat6.maximum - cat6.minimum)) + (cat6.minimum);
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.